# Rebooting program after input() automatically on python

Tags: python

I have a question about python 3.4.1

So suppose you have a program like this:

```
name = input("What is your name?")
print("Hi", name ,'!')
```

So you get:

> .>>> What is your name?

So you type in you James and you get back:

> .>>> Hi James!

Then after it prints this little message, it automatically resets, and goes back to:

> .>>> What is you name?

Thanks for you time! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while True:
    name = input("What is your name?")
    print("Hi", name ,'!')
```

Use a `while loop`

You need some condition to break out of the loop:

```
while True:
    name = input("Enter your name or press q to quit")
    if name == "q": 
        break    # if user enters `q`, we will end the loop with this break statement
    print("Hi", name ,'!') # or else just print the name
```

A nice [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm)  on while loops.

Comment: Thank you once again Padraic!

Comment: @JamesH., have a look at learnpythonthehardway, it will get you going on all the basics and you will have fun too ;) http://learnpythonthehardway.org/